# Burninate the [blank] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[blank](/questions/tagged/blank) tag in itself does not make any sense.

It has no tag wiki, there are 439 questions tagged as blank and just 1 follower.

Should the tag be burniated?